# how to convert netty's FullHttpRequest to HttpServletRequest

Tags: spring-mvc, netty

I want to configure Netty in Spring MVC. Here's an example showing how to bootstrap Netty with a handler supporting Servlets (which in turn will delegate the job to Spring MVC) https://github.com/rstoyanchev/netty-spring-mvc.

My problem:

The *TestController* can't get *RequestParam* when method = post. Why this happen and how can I solve it?, thanks!

Comment: Try use this: https://github.com/code4craft/netty-servlet/blob/master/src/main/java/us/codecraft/netty_servlet/connector/netty/NettyHttpServletRequestAdaptor.java